# Oracle sql or plsql converting rows to column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, case

I have a table1 in below structure and sample. Need to be show it as table 2. Can anyone please help in this.

Table 1

```
id  Month   Days
1   january 20
2   january 19
3   january 20
4   january 21
5   january 22
6   january 23
1   February    18
2   February    17
3   February    16
4   February    15
5   February    16
6   February    18
6   February    18
```

Table 2:

```
id  January February
1   20  18
2   19  17
3   20  16
4   21  15
5   22  16
6   23  18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id
     , sum(case when month = 'January' then days end) as january
     , sum(case when month = 'February' then days end) as february
  from table1
 group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

case statement gives you best solution for your query :

```
select id,
      sum(
       case when 
               month = 'January' then  days 
                                 else '' end) as january, 
      sum(
        case when 
               month = 'February' then days  
                                 else ''  end) as February    
  from table1
 group by id;
```